# componentWillReceiveProps rendered twice in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react js I have a child component it is written like this way

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      volume: this.props.forcasted_volume,
     yearValue:Number(localStorage.getItem('year'))//it's 2017 value
      loading: false
    };
  }
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log(
      'before if condition...',
      this.state.yearValue,
      Number(localStorage.getItem('plan_year'))
    );
    if (
      this.state.yearValue ==
      localStorage.getItem('plan_year')
    ) {
      console.log('inside if condition.....', nextProps);
      this.state = {

        volume: nextProps.forcasted_volume,

        loading: false
      };
    } else this.setState({ loading: false });
  }
```

now my question is I saw my `componentWillReceiveProps` called twice first time my `this.state.yearValue` is 2017 what I expected but 2nd time tis value it shows `undefined` I don't understand 2 things why it called twice? can I control it? and why 2nd time it's value became `undefined`?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps will be called on every parent render. So its possible the prop updated in parent because of some reason or you mutated the props

Comment: but why my `yearValue` was undefined 2nd time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this.state =...` instead of setstate. Setstate only changes the values of the provided properties where 'this.state =' changes the entire collection. You should use `setState`, because this also cares of the re-rendering.

Comment: that's why yearValue was undefined 2nd time?

Comment: This is completely true. Overriding globally the state leaves the value of yearValue to undefined.

Comment: Vihang, yes correct, because initially you set it in the constructor, but cleared it later in the first call of componentwillreceiveprops.

Answer (score 0):

Props has nothing to do with current class. This is a property of parent class/ subscribed reducers. Check if you are re-rendering parent for second time, with some `setState` or other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if... statement, update this.state to 
this.setState({volume: nextProps.forcasted_volume, loading: false}), just as you have in your else statement.